# Unable to bind Autocomplete using jQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to make autocomplete  using jqueryUi, but unable to bind data to it.

```
$("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
        source:
       function () {
           $.ajax({
               url: "SearchCustomer?key=" + $("#CustomerName").val(),
               async: false,
               dataType:"json",
               success: function (data) {
                   return data.ResultList;
               }
           })
       },
        minLength: 0, autoFocus: true, delay: 1000
    });
```

My Result of ajax is -

```
{"Message":null,"Successfull":false,"Id":0,"Result":null,"ResultList":["Customer 2","Kohl\u0027s Corp","Test Corp"]}
```

if i use this, then it work fine

```
$("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
            source:["Customer 2","Kohl\u0027s Corp","Test Corp"],
            minLength: 0, autoFocus: true, delay: 1000
        });
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: why don't you add "dataType : json" to the ajax request and check ? If that works for you...

Comment: i tried but that even not work, i think its because of ajax..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with $.ajax, could you please wrap the returned data with the response like  `response(data.ResultList);`

```
$("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
               url: "SearchCustomer?key=" + $("#CustomerName").val(),
               dataType : "json",
               success: function (data) {
                   response(data.ResultList);
               }
           });
    },
    minLength: 0, 
    autoFocus: true, 
    delay: 1000
});
```

Comment: +1, although you can use `request.term` instead of `$('...').val()`